# Response is empty when hosted in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

The code is working on a local server but when it was hosted in cpanel it return an empty response.[image: on a local server , the response.]
[image: hosted on cpanel , the response is empty] . Is this because of the code? or a rule or is it because of cpanel

```
$data=array();

$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.*,a.date_added AS date_added2,a.status AS entry_status,a.added_by AS entry_provider FROM entries a WHERE a.status = 'Approved' ORDER BY a.id DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
    $data[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: View Source (Ctrl + U) on the browser and see if there is any output there. Also enable error in your script and check if there is any.

Comment: i have tried still getting 0 response.

Comment: `echo 'test'; die;` Put this at the start of your file and see if it prints.

Comment: yeah it prints , but it does not read the query

Comment: That means there is no data on your live server that matches the query criteria. So result set is empty which in turn makes JSON empty.

Comment: but i have tried running the query on phpmyadmin inside cpanel and it returns the correct data , is there a problem with the code i have pasted above? that does not fit on cpanel

Comment: Code looks ok except starting tag of `PHP` i.e. `<?php`. Check if this is present.

Comment: it does it is repsent  Sir

Comment: ok got it. `mysql_error` Change this to `mysqli_error($con)`; You are using deprecated version of `mysql`

Comment: do is still need to include die ?

Comment: yes, `or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: it returns an empty array

Comment: still the same, empty

Comment: There is nothing more I can help you from here. You need to enable error in PHP and check logs. Also ensure data is present in your database. The code looks fine to me.

Comment: i have added but it returns empty but when i remove the mysqli_error($con) is returns nulllnull.